# How and why are cells irradiated in human-rodent hybrid cell biology?

Tags: molecular-genetics, human-genetics

When human-rodent hybrids are made the amount of human chromosome in the hybrid can be reduced by irradiation. Why and how exactly is this irradiation step performed?

Comment: "Why and how exactly is it performed?" Are you specifically asking about irradiation?

Comment: Im asking chiefly why it is done

Comment: And the principle behind it

Comment: I've made an edit that tries to specify that a bit better.

Answer (score 1):

Human cells are irradiated with X rays (to fragment the DNA) and then fused with rodent cells. This is useful for mapping because closely linked markers are more likely to appear in the same hybrid: there is a lower probability of radiation induced breakage between the markers because they are close together.